# Display extra data from a Search Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rubygems

Currently learning through a Udemy Course but changed the lecture to something I am more interested in developing.

Project Basis:
- using Gem Flightstats-flex to pull flight data
- trying to display associated info from a search query

Current setup

app/controllers/trackers_controller.rb

```
class TrackersController < ApplicationController

  def search
    @tracker = FlightTracker.new_from_lookup(params[:tracker])
    render 'users/my_tracker'
  end

end
```

app/models/flight_tracker.rb

```
class FlightTracker < ActiveRecord::Base

    self.table_name='trackers'

    def self.new_from_lookup(tracker)
      flight_track = FlightStats::FlightStatus.by_flight_id(tracker)
      # flight_position = FlightStats::FlightStatus.track_by_flight_id(tracker)

end
```

This is where the problem happens, when I remove `#` from `flight_position = FlightStats::FlightStatus.track_by_flight_id(tracker)`

- the results overwrite the top
- if I use the line only it displays and vice versa for the top line

app/views/users/my_tracker.html.erb the data does render

```
<h1>
  My Tracker
</h1>

<h3>Search for Flights</h3>
<div id="tracker-lookup">
  <%= form_tag search_trackers_path, method: :get, id: "tracker-lookup-form" do %>
    <div class="form-group row no-padding text-center col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <%= text_field_tag :tracker, params[:tracker], 
                                  placeholder: "Stock ticker symbol", autofocus: true,
                                  class: "form-control search-box input-lg" %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <%= button_tag(type: :submit, class: "btn btn-lg btn-success") do %>
          <i class="fa fa-search"></i> Look up a tracker
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>

  <% end %>
</div>

<div class="well results-block">
  <%=@tracker.inspect%>
    <strong>ID: </strong> <%#= @tracker&.flight_id %>
    <strong>Code: </strong> <%#= @tracker&.carrier_fs_code %>
    <strong>Number: </strong> <%#= @tracker&.flight_number %>
    <strong>Departure: </strong> <%#= @tracker&.departure_airport_fs_code %>
    <strong>Arrival: </strong> <%#= @tracker&.arrival_airport_fs_code %>
    <%# <strong>Departure Terminal: </strong> <%= @tracker&.departure_terminal %> %>
  <%=@position.inspect%>  
</div>
```

So when an user searches for a `.by_flight_id` , I want it to show the related data for `.track_by_flight_id`

Hoping to move to the next stage of more data associations after a query is completed.

Comment: Aggregate results of both requests into object and render it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As illustration for my comment

```
def self.new_from_lookup(tracker)
  flight_track = FlightStats::FlightStatus.by_flight_id(tracker)
  flight_position = FlightStats::FlightStatus.track_by_flight_id(tracker)
  OpenStruct.new(flight_track: flight_track, flight_position: flight_position)
end
```

Then you'll need to rewrite template **my_tracker.html.erb** to handle new data structure

Comment: For example: tracker.flight_track.flight_id instead of tracker.flight_id.